How to log which application process removes a file from the server?
I have a situation and have described it here .
In short: Images from WP are randomly missing from the server while being kept in the database. I am confident that this is done through application and not by some user.
I am thinking of implementing a script to record when image from specific folder is removed from the server. I want to know which application is removing it in as much detail as possible.
All I need is a few logs. Is it possible and how to do it?
UPDATE
I do not have root access to the server, best if we look at it as it is a shared hosting on Cpanel

It is possible to do, by using the Linux auditd subsystem...
Edit /etc/auditd/rules.d/audit.rules to have at least the following
## First rule - delete all
-D

## Increase the buffers to survive stress events.
## Make this bigger for busy systems
## default was 8192;  that * 1024

-b 8388608

## This determine how long to wait in burst of events

--backlog_wait_time 60000

## Set failure mode to syslog
## 0 = silent; 1 = syslog; 2 = nuclear kernel panic shutdown system

-f 0

## here are the specific rules to capture deletes

# adjust auid to be auid >=0 or between a certain range if you think you need to to find the culprit; may blow up the audit.log to gigabytes in seconds however

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S rename,unlink,rmdir,renameat,unlinkat -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k DELETIONS
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S rename,unlink,rmdir,renameat,unlinkat -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k DELETIONS

Also look over /etc/audit/auditd.conf but the default configuration is typically acceptable; maybe change or set log_format = ENRICHED within.
systemctl enable auditd
service auditd start    # unless you prefer to reboot

service auditd status -l    # verify auditd is running and audit.d rules was valid

Logs of the deletion will be recorded in /var/log/audit/audit.log or whatever log_file= is set to in auditd.conf
Search within audit.log for the keyword DELETIONS or whatever the -k value is tagged on that rule.
https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-understanding_audit_log_files
And for rules you can also set up a watch rule on specific folders/files; for example -w /var/log -p wa -K WATCHKEY

Will this work on shared hosting in Cpanel without root access?

without root access, no. auditd is all root permission stuff.
